# What do we call this kind of vocal effect?

Tags: vocals, effect, metal

In this youtube video, the vocal sound effect start from 0.29 to 0.32.
I was looking for a tutorial how to make that kind of vocal effect.

I tried to type on youtube search such as "metal drop vocal effect" , "tape-stop vocal effect", but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Sounds like the sample is chopped up and played several times with cut applied. Cut is basically when the next sound cuts the previous one. Try taking your audio sample and modifying into something short, like half a second or so. After you get that done you have to arrange it in your DAW so that they play one after another very quickly (That cut effect was only 3 seconds in your video). Some kind of filter is on that too I'm not sure which one exactly. Try Love Philter if you're working in FL Studio. If that doesn't work out, just message me back. We can work this thing out.

Comment: Hey Daniel, seems like you nailed the subject pretty well, why not put your comment in a answer?

Comment: Sounds like a 1/4 second decay filter before each cut, but only for the 3 seconds Daniel mentioned.